# Guass Jordan Elimination maple code

Tags: maple

i was just researching the net and came across this; how would one go about computing this??

Question: The **Gauss-Jordan method** is similar to **Gaussian Elimination** but creates zeroes also above
the pivot (thus no back substitution is needed). Write out the **full algorithm in Maple code**,
always starting with the normalization of the current row, then creating the zeroes. Avoid
unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some hints by looking at some of the procedures in Maple which can compute the reduced row echelon form (RREF).

One of the simplest examples, with not too much cruft at beginning and end, is the gaussjord command in the now deprecated linalg package.

```
interface(verboseproc=3):
print(linalg[gaussjord]);
```

Somewhat more obscured by its surrounding code is a version within the LUDecomposition command of the newer LinearAlgebra package. It's a little tricky to see which part of the procedure computes the RREF, and so viewing it is slightly easier if done using the `showstat` command. For example, using the line numbers in Maple 17,

```
showstat(LinearAlgebra:-LUDecomposition,228..339);
```

In the code for `LUDecomposition`, the key bits are the loops with computation of the Matrix `mU` (Gaussian elimination to get row echelon form), followed by the loops with further computation of the Matrix `mR` (further reduction of rows to the right of leading nonzero entry) to get the final RREF. If you just want the RREF then it's not really necessary to split the row reduction into two subtasks like this, and you won't be interested in the `mL` and `mU` pieces.

If you reduce whole rows at once then you might try using `LinearAlgebra:-RowOperation` instead of some inner loops. That command can swap rows, or add a multiple of one row to another, or scale a single row.

You could also search the web for "pseudocode" and "RREF".